# Task Cancellation Token Not Being Triggered

Tags: c#, winforms, task, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I am trying to use tasks to send emails. That part is working but I also want to allow the user to cancel an email before it is sent. Currently I am storing a list of Tasks in a List and when a user pushes a button it goes and finds the Task by matching d's and then activates its cancellation via a token.

However it doesn't seem to ever get called. It finds the task in the list but the call to tm.TokenSource.Cancel(); doesn't seem to do anything.

Email Button Click Event

```
private void SendEmailBtn_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
            Email defaultEmail = Email.GetEmail(Session.CurrentUser.CurrentSetting.DefaultEmailId);
            if (defaultEmail != null)
            {
                string statusId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                EmailStatusForm.EmailStatusList.Add(new EmailStatus(statusId, defaultEmail.Username, defaultEmail.Username, DateTime.Now, EmailStatus.StatusCode.Sending));
                Session.HandleForm(EmailStatusForm.GetInstance());
                EmailStatusForm.GetInstance().DesktopLocation = new Point(Width + 50, DesktopLocation.Y);


                CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
                var token = tokenSource.Token;
                Task task = new Task(() => SendEmail(statusId, defaultEmail, defaultEmail.Username, subject, body, token), token);                 
                Session.TaskList.Add(new TaskManager(statusId, task, tokenSource));
                task.Start();
           }

}
```

Send Mail

```
private void SendEmail(string id, Email sender, string recipiant, string subject, string body, CancellationToken ct)
{            
                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(sender.SMTP);
                try
                {                    
                    MailAddress from = new MailAddress(sender.Username, Session.CurrentUser.FirstName + " " + Session.CurrentUser.Surname, Encoding.UTF8);
                    MailAddress to = new MailAddress(recipiant);
                    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
                    message.Body = body;
                    message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                    message.Subject = subject;
                    message.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;                                                                           
                    client.SendAsync(message, message);
                }
                catch (TaskCanceledException)
                {
                    EmailStatus es = EmailStatus.GetEmailStatus(id);
                    if (es != null)
                    {
                        if (es.Status != EmailStatus.StatusCode.Failed && es.Status != EmailStatus.StatusCode.Sent)
                        {
                            client.SendAsyncCancel();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Session.Debug("Error: Cannot cancel. Email has alreadt been sent or failed");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Session.Debug("Email staus not found using id: " + id);
                    }
                    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }
}
```

Task Manager Class

```
public class TaskManager
{
        private string Id { get;}
        private Task Task { get; }
        private CancellationTokenSource TokenSource { get; }

        public TaskManager(string id, Task task, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
        {
            Id = id;
            Task = task;
            TokenSource = tokenSource;
        }

        public static void CancelTask(string id)
        {
            foreach(TaskManager tm in Session.TaskList)
            {
                if (tm.Id == id)
                {
                    Session.Debug("Found the task in task list " + id);
                    tm.TokenSource.Cancel();
                }
            }            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well it doesn't seem to do anything because your `SmtpClient` doesn't consume the token, and most interestlingly your `ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();` is in the catch block. So essentially your e-mail sending code does not use the cancellation token.

Comment: I have tried if(ct.IsCancellationRequested){} else { } instead of the try catch but it didn't work either.

Comment: You need to find a version of SmtpClient that takes a cancellation token, otherwise it does nothing and you can't actually cancel the send of your e-mail

Comment: I thought SMTP client comes built in with the cancel token?

Comment: Since I don't know what type you're using I can't check the doco for you but if you're using Microsoft's `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` then you should use a different method where you can pass in the `CancellationToken`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendmailasync?view=net-6.0#system-net-mail-smtpclient-sendmailasync(system-net-mail-mailmessage-system-threading-cancellationtoken)

Comment: I am using System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.

Comment: *You keep using that cancellation token there...*  [A Tour of Task, Part 9: Delegate Tasks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/03/a-tour-of-task-part-9-delegate-tasks.html)

Comment: I might be missing something, but in `SendEmailBtn_ClickAsync` your `CancellationTokenSource` `tokenSource` is local and you pass its `Token` into `SendMail`. How can you then hope to cancel on `tokenSource` if it has since gone out of scope>